# The formal parameter “@mode” was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spCertificationType 
    @result nvarchar(15) output,
    @mode int 
AS
BEGIN
    if @mode = 1
    begin
        exec spGeneratedID 2, @result output
        print @result
    end
END
```

but when I tried to execute it,it has this error

> The formal parameter “@mode” was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

I tried to set `@mode` as output like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spCertificationType 
    @result nvarchar(15) output,
    @mode int output
AS
BEGIN
    if @mode = 1
    begin
        exec spGeneratedID 2, @result output
        print @result
    end
END
```

but the it returns a null value.

Any fix for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post you code to execute procedure.

Comment: I think that output params must be at the end (although not sure). Try to change places of `@result` and `@mode`

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov that was awesome!that was the solution..thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the sequence of parameter in store procedure is that first use input parameter then use output parameter:-
you can see this link for more knowledge of store procedure:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-To-Write-a-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spCertificationType 

     @mode int,
     @result nvarchar(15) output
 AS
 BEGIN
     if @mode = 1
   begin
    exec spGeneratedID 2, @result output
    print @result
   end
END
```

Comment: It would be really useful if you could add a bit of info about why this solves the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error a different way.

1. I had removed the OUTPUT statement after a parameter in my SP.
2. I then got the error.
3. I then went back to the SQLDataSource Configure Data Source wizard and went through the steps again.  I discovered that changing the SP made the wizard delete the settings associated with the parameter that used to have OUTPUT after it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had declared the `OUTPUT` parameter last but was also getting a similar exception.

I moved the default parameters (like `@var FLOAT = null`) to the end after the output parameter then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also get this error if you didn't declare the parameter as OUTPUT in the stored procedure, but when you execute the stored procedure you use the OUTPUT keyword when specifying the parameter (or, in my case, using it in .NET code and specifying that it is an output parameter there).