# The formal parameter ""@response"" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, output

Yes, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219733/the-formal-parameter-mode-was-not-declared-as-an-output-parameter-but-the-ac) question.  No, it has not solved my problems.

I am working on an application in VB.Net that interfaces with an SQL Server Database.  Currently I am trying to have the VB.Net app Execute the following Stored Procedure on the Database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddSupplierAddress(
    @Supplier VARCHAR(100),
    @Street   VARCHAR(100),
    @City     VARCHAR(50),
    @Region   VARCHAR(50),
    @Code     VARCHAR(7),
    @Info     VARCHAR(500) = NULL,
    @response NVARCHAR(500) = OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SupplierID INT, @RegionID INT
    SELECT @SupplierID = supplier_id
      FROM suppliers
     WHERE supplier_name = @Supplier
    IF @SupplierID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @response = 'Could not add address to Supplier "' + @Supplier + '".  Supplier does not exist.'
        RETURN
    END
    SELECT @RegionID = region_id
      FROM regions
     WHERE region_name = @Region
    IF @RegionID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @response = 'Could not add address to Supplier "' + @Supplier + '". Region "' + @Region + '" does not exist.'
        RETURN
    END
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT supplier_id, street FROM supplier_addresses WHERE supplier_id = @SupplierID AND street = @Street))
    BEGIN
        SET @response = 'Could not add address to Supplier "' + @Supplier + '".  Address already exists in database.'
        RETURN
    END
    BEGIN TRANSACTION AddSuppAddr
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT supplier_addresses(supplier_id, street, city, region_id, zip_code, notes)
        VALUES (@SupplierID, @Street, @City, @RegionID, @Code, @Info)
        COMMIT TRANSACTION AddSuppAddr
        SET @response = 'Success'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION AddSuppAddr
        DECLARE @varErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @varErrorSeverity INT, @varErrorState INT;
        SELECT @varErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @varErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @varErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        RAISERROR(@varErrorMessage, @varErrorSeverity, @varErrorState);
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Now I have run this Procedure on the database itself using the following:

```
DECLARE @Resp NVARCHAR(500)
EXEC AddSupplierAddress 'Test Name', '123 main st.', 'Hamilton', 'Ontario', 'L84B5N', NULL, @Resp
PRINT @Resp
```

The procedure works fine.  (One small issue I am having is that `@Resp` never gets set to my output value when testing these procedures on the database, but that is a different problem that I am not trying to solve here).  In my VB.Net program I am trying to run this procedure using the following code:

```
Private Sub CreateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles createBtn.Click
    If CreateSupplier(supplierTxt.Text, websiteTxt.Text, True) Then
        Dim message As String = ""
        If setAddress Then
            If AddSupplierAddress(supplierTxt.Text, streetTxt.Text, cityTxt.Text, regionTxt.Text, codeTxt.Text, infoTxt.Text, True) Then
                message = "Supplier and address have been added to the database."
            Else
                DeleteSupplier(supplierTxt.Text)
                Return
            End If
        Else
            message = "Supplier has been added to the database."
        End If
        If MessageBox.Show(message & vbCrLf & "Would you like to add any Contacts?", "Data Added", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim contact As New NewContactForm(supplierTxt.Text, False, True) With {
                .MdiParent = MdiParent
            }
            contact.Show()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function AddSupplierAddress(ByVal supplier As String,
                                   ByVal street As String,
                                   ByVal city As String,
                                   ByVal region As String,
                                   ByVal code As String,
                                   Optional info As String = "",
                                   Optional displayError As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim errorMsg As String = ""
    Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("AddSupplierAddress")
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Supplier", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = supplier
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = street
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = city
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Region", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = region
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = code
    If Not info.Equals("") Then CMD.Parameters.Add("@Info", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info
    If ExecuteCMDWithReturnValue(CMD, errorMsg) Then
        Return True
    Else
        If displayError Then
            MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "Database Error")
            Return False
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function ExecuteCMDWithReturnValue(ByRef CMD As SqlCommand, ByRef errorMessage As String) As Boolean
    Try
        OpenDBConnection()
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@response", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        CMD.Connection = DB_CONNECTION
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim result As String = CMD.Parameters("@response").Value
        If result.Equals("Success") Then
            ExecuteCMDWithReturnValue = True
        Else
            errorMessage = result
            ExecuteCMDWithReturnValue = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Database Error: " & ex.Message)
        ExecuteCMDWithReturnValue = False
    Finally
        CloseDBConnection()
    End Try
End Function
```

Now as I said above, I am not getting this error when I run the Stored Procedure on the Database.  What is even weirder is I have another setup of procedures that are coded the exact same, with the only difference being every instance of `supplier` is replaced with `customer` and they all work fine!

The specific error I am getting is in the title, but so you don't have to scroll up its:

> The formal parameter ""@response"" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

What could be causing my problem?

Comment: `@response NVARCHAR(500) = OUTPUT` is a legal declaration that will give `@response` the default value of `'OUTPUT'` if not passed in, since T-SQL allows unquoted strings here, for... reasons. But what you want is `@response NVARCHAR(500) OUTPUT`.

Comment: .......HOW DID THAT `=` GET THERE!?!?! /facepalm

Comment: You think that's bad? Try putting `@from DATETIME = GETDATE` there, thinking it's going to give you a sensible default value if the parameter is not supplied. (Hint: it won't.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Shouldn't that be an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Meta-Knight: I suppose, although I have no idea if this will ever be useful and found again by future readers...

Comment: Incidentally, getting `@Resp` set correctly from T-SQL also involves `OUTPUT`: `EXEC AddSupplierAddress 'Test Name', '123 main st.', 'Hamilton', 'Ontario', 'L84B5N', NULL, @Resp OUTPUT`. It would have given you the same error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the tip :)  Will make testing SQL code in the future easier (hopefully)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations, you ran into a nasty T-SQL gotcha. It "allows" string parameter defaults to be specified without quotes, so that

```
@response NVARCHAR(500) = OUTPUT
```

Is actually equivalent to

```
@response NVARCHAR(500) = 'OUTPUT'
```

Which is of course not the same thing as declaring the parameter as an output parameter, since that's

```
@response NVARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
```

This is especially bad because the default values allow only constants -- not functions or expressions -- and yet the quotes being optional allows for some really misleading declarations:

```
@from DATETIME = GETDATE
```

This will fail only when the procedure is called without specifying a value for `@from`: at that point the string `'GETDATE'` will be converted to `DATETIME` (which, of course, fails).

Comment: Hopefully this answer could be helpful to others in the future.  At the very least, people with the same error may learn about the annoying T-SQL gotcha....